# label \psline and orient label in the direction of the arrow

Tags: pstricks, arrows

How can I label the \psline entity with a label that is positioned/oriented (not placed horizontally taking too much space) on the line itself?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(18,18)
\psset{linecolor=DodgerBlue4, tickcolor=white, subtickcolor=DodgerBlue4, gridcolor=DodgerBlue4, gridlabelcolor=white}%
\psset{linewidth=0.05pt, tickwidth=0.05pt, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, subticks=2, subtickwidth=0.025pt, labels=none}
\psframe[linewidth=0.05pt](0,0)(18,18)
\psset{gridwidth=0.05pt, subgriddiv=1}
\psgrid(0,0)(18,18)

% insert circles
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](9,9){8}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](9,9){4}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](12,8){4}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](9,6){4}

% insert arrows
\psline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=red](9,9) (12,8)
\psline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=magenta]{->}(9,9) (9,6)
\psline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=blue]{->}(12,8) (9,6)
\psline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=blue]{->}(9,9) (6.5,7)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: If you want small labels, you can add at the beginning `\everypsbox{\footnotesize}`, say, (if you're in textmode) or `\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}` (in math mode).

Answer (score 2):

You can either add invisible `\pcline`s or work with `\pcline`s instead of `\psline`s. I illustrate a few possibilities below. (Now with `DodgerBlue4`, big thanks to @Bernad!)

```
\documentclass[x11names]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{DodgerBlue4}{RGB}{3,3,192}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(18,18)
\psset{linecolor=DodgerBlue4, tickcolor=white, subtickcolor=DodgerBlue4, gridcolor=DodgerBlue4, gridlabelcolor=white}%
\psset{linewidth=0.05pt, tickwidth=0.05pt, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, subticks=2, subtickwidth=0.025pt, labels=none}
\psframe[linewidth=0.05pt](0,0)(18,18)
\psset{gridwidth=0.05pt, subgriddiv=1}
\psgrid(0,0)(18,18)

% insert circles
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](9,9){8}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](9,9){4}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](12,8){4}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.2, linewidth=0.1](9,6){4}

% insert arrows
% method 1: insert an invisible \pcline
\psline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=red](9,9) (12,8)
\pcline[linestyle=none](9,9)(12,8)\aput{:U}{label 1}
% method 2: shorter: use \pcline instead of \psline
% note, however, that you need to remove the spaces between the coordinates then
\pcline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=magenta]{->}(9,9)(9,6)
\aput{:U}{label 2}
\pcline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=blue]{->}(12,8)(9,6)
\Aput{label 3}
\pcline[arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt,linestyle=solid, linecolor=blue]{->}(9,9)(6.5,7)
\bput{:U}{label 4}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `DodgerBlue4` is defined by the `x11names` option of `xcolor` (which is loaded – without option – by `pstricks`.

Comment: As pstricks loads xcolor without options, you can pass  `x11names` with the document class options. Many named colours come from this option, or `svgnames`

Answer (score 1):

With less keystrokes:

```
\documentclass[x11names,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(18,18)
\psset{linecolor=DodgerBlue4, subtickcolor=DodgerBlue4, gridcolor=DodgerBlue4,
 linewidth=0.05pt, tickwidth=0.05pt, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, subticks=2, subtickwidth=0.025pt, labels=none}
\psframe[linewidth=0.05pt](0,0)(18,18)
\psgrid[gridwidth=0.05pt, subgriddiv=1](0,0)(18,18) 
    % insert circles
\pscircle[linewidth=0.1](9,9){8}
\pscircle[linewidth=0.1](9,9){4}
\pscircle[linewidth=0.1](12,8){4}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.2,linewidth=0.1](9,6){4}
% insert arrows
\psset{arrows=->,linewidth=2.5pt}
\pcline[linecolor=red](9,9)(12,8)   \aput{:U}{label 1}
\pcline[linecolor=magenta](9,9)(9,6)\aput{:U}{label 2}
\pcline[linecolor=blue](12,8)(9,6)  \Aput{label 3}
\pcline[linecolor=blue](9,9)(6.5,7) \bput{:U}{label 4}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]